# AngularJs: Multiple columns with adjustable height

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, layout

I am currently transferring a project from jQuery to AngularJS.

I receive "articles" from a server in JSON format with **title**, **authors**, **date** and **abstract**. I display them as divs the following way:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="one-article" ng-repeat="article in articles">
    <p class="article-title">{{article.title}}</p>
    <p class="article-authors"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      {{article.authors}}
    </p>
    <p class="article-date">{{ article.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Because I use Bootstrap `col-sm-4`, I have 3 columns in wide screen. This looks really good.

**My problem:**

I now want to include the article **abstract**, and its length can vary from nothing to a few (<100) words. For this reason, the display looks weird. I would like to find an elegant solution to have different height for each `div` so that the whole display is optimized, without any blank holes in between lines of three articles.

**What I tried**

- While using jQuery, I went for Masonry javascript library. Worked OK but my angularjs skills are still limited and I didn't manage to transfer. Also, if I could avoid any external library, that would be great (Website is suppose to also work on very low resources/bandwidth).
- Put a very large height for the `one-article` div, or cut down the abstract size to a finite number of characters. Both options work but are not AT ALL what I try to obtain...

**My best result so far**

When receiving an article from the website, define a column number and then use a filter in angularJS:

`ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:{column:1}"`

While this work, I don't find it very "elegant" because

- I have to recalculate all the columns number every time one article is removed by the user
- I can't use a global orderBy filter
- I have to repeat the code in the view 3 times...

If anyone with more experience in angularJS has an idea, or worst case scenario an external plugin (but small if possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of lists instead and repeat over those lists. To fill the lists just do it the same way you calculated the "column" values, that can be done with a relatively small amount of cpu. The extra lists will barely take any memory at all since they only contain extra pointers, so that is not an issue either.